# Is there a term to describe when students are in one classroom for most of the day?

Tags: terminology

When I was in elementary school, I was in a single classroom the entire day. I would have different teachers come in and give classes, but we as students wouldn't change our classroom. When I was in high school, we were in two classrooms, first half and second half of the day.

There seems to be a term for every single possible classroom arrangement, but I haven't found one for this. I've seen it once called "Homeroom," but the Internet seems to disagree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeroom amongst other places). Any suggestions?

Additional context: The company I'm working for is building a school software so terminology is critical when initially setting up courses/classrooms etc. We've spent a ton of time researching terminology, but this one has us completely stuck.

Comment: Hmm, nothing comes to mind. Can you give an example of one of the other classroom arrangements that has a specific term?

Comment: The term I'm familiar with for different teachers with different subjects is departmentalized or platoon teaching. I looked for a more specific term to refer to your situation and didn't find one; places I found that described departmentalized structures and mentioned the possibility of either teachers or students moving did not associate any term with it. It's quite possible one doesn't exist. I pinged the math educators chat in case someone over there has experience, perhaps there is a term used in a research setting. Good luck!

Comment: All of my secondary school life (middle and high school) were in a fixed classroom, i.e. the whole class were in a fix class room, All of the teachers came to our class room to teach. Even music lessons were taught in our class. The location is Taiwan.The time was 5 decades ago.

Answer (score 3):

Something close may be a “floating teacher model”.

A room is predominantly occupied by one instructor then another comes in during the primary instructor’s prep period to teach his or her lesson.  There’s no reason one room would be restricted to only two teachers in this practice. “Cart” teachers or “mobile” teachers are also commonly used terms for these roles. While there *is* research on this practice, I haven’t come across any where *all* teachers are subject to moving between rooms. That’s not to say a universal term for the structure does not exist.

Comment: In Italy, apart for subjects like gym and some labs, all high-school teachers move among classrooms. At university, it's the same.

Comment: My understanding from what I’ve read is that it works the same way in Japanese high schools as well. Not sure if they use the same term for it as this answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is (or was) the norm in Germany, that students stay put and the teacher moves from class to class. It is called a "floating teacher" arrangement. https://woman.thenest.com/floating-teacher-10350.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've ever had a situation where *all* of the classes where taught in the same room. Disregarding the obvious such as gym classes, in elementary school we did have a solitary classroom for most of the subjects though.

I am however not familiar with a specific term that exist to describe this though, perhaps you can simply refer to it as having a "designated classroom" that is specific to the class as opposed to having subject specific classrooms? This is a fascinating question, will need to explore this one further.